# Нахождение одного из чисел, если дан НОК двух чисел и второе число

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм

Не могу понять, как эту задачу можно решить без "тупого" перебора чисел от НОК/данное число, до самого НОК. Число, которое нужно найти, должно быть минимальным подходящим к данным.

Можно выразить искомое число через НОД(неизвестный)*НОК/данное_число, но тогда не понятно, как обратно идти от НОД к числу. Также можно разложить НОК и дынное число на простые множители, по ним искать третье (опорная точка -- произведение чисел, которые есть в разложении НОК но нет в разложении данного нам числа), но тут как раз перебор с проверкой (правда, чуть поменьше). Второй вариант сложнее при очень больших числах.

Перебором нельзя т.к. числа будут огромные. Написать код не прошу, просто интересна сама суть решения, правильно ли я вообще думаю.

Comment: В общем виде задача имеет много решений. Например, пусть НОК=84, а число - 28. Вторым числом может быть и 3, и 12, и 6, и 21... Ну, конечно, сам ряд возможных решений выписать - это просто, но у вас же вопрос о конкретном числе...

Comment: Да, вдогонку - никакого перебора, хотя без разложения самого второго числа на простые сомножители, похоже, не обойтись...

Comment: Так а почему нельзя просто разделить НОК на известное число? Сразу получится один из возможных ответов.

Comment: @Yaant *почему нельзя просто разделить НОК на известное число?* НОК = 4; x=2. Поделишь - получишь 2. Однако правильный (кстати, единственный) ответ - 4.

Comment: @Akina Да, что-то я ступил, теперь уже и не пойму, как я рассуждал, когда решил, что так можно. :)

Comment: @Yaant Ты просто не учёл общие простые делители (и их возможную кратность).

Comment: @Harry, да, не указал, что найти надо минимальное подходящее число, исправил

Comment: @pavel если думаете, что нашли решение, как ответ опубликуйте. Сейчас не ясно, что вы делите, gcd чего находите, до каких пор повторяете и как это позволяет ответ найти.

Comment: @jfs сделал ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Раскладываем на простые множители НОК. Получаем список множитель-кратность (например, при разложении 12 будет два множителя - 2 с кратностью 2 и 3 с кратностью 1). Назовём его **список1**. Раскладываем на простые множители имеющееся число (назовём его **список2**). Далее обрабатываем оба списка, создавая **список3**.

- Если некий множитель отсутствует в **список1**, но имеется в **список2**, задача нерешаема.
- Если кратность множителя в **список1** меньше его кратности в **список2**, задача нерешаема.
- Если некий множитель имеется в **список1**, но отсутствует в **список2**, он помещается в **список3** с той же кратностью, что и в **список1**.
- Если кратность множителя в **список1** больше его кратности в **список2**, он помещается в **список3** с той же кратностью, что и в **список1**.
- Если некий множитель имеется в **список1** и **список2** с одинаковой кратностью, он помещается в **список3** с кратностью 0 (ноль).

Перемножая множители из **список3** с учётом кратности, получаем минимальное решение. Остальные решения получаем увеличением кратности одного или нескольких множителей в **список3**, но не превышая их кратности в **список1**.

Всё.

Comment: Благодарю! Никак не мог полностью собрать мысли, но Вы сделали это прекрасно, спасибо))

Comment: Улучшение (огромное ускорение такого алгоритма): делим НОК(a,b) на a (допустим, что а дано, b надо найти) -- это будет изначальное b -- и смотрим какие просты множители есть в его разложении. Потом для каждого множителя цикл: пока можем делить а на множитель, результат (b) умножаем на множитель. ВСЕ.

Comment: @Johanna посмотрите на код в моём ответе (на предмет связи с действиями, которые вы описали).

Answer (score 5):

Если любое решение интересует, то тривиальным (наибольшим) ответом является сам НОК, т.к. `max(max(e, d), d) == max(e, d)`, см. [каноническое разложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9A). Если известно `b` и `lcm(a, b)`, и требуется любое `a` найти, то ответ: 
`a = lcm(a, b)` то есть:

```
lcm(a, b) == lcm(lcm(a, b), b)
```

Чтобы минимальное из возможных решений найти, в разложении на простые множители, кратность простых чисел в наименьшем общем кратном (НОК) равна максимуму кратности обоих чисел (см. [каноническое разложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9A)), поэтому кратность в искомом (минимальном среди возможно нескольких решений) либо равна кратности в НОК, либо нулю, если кратность в первом числе равна кратности в НОК:

```py
# a = p**d * ...; b = p**e * ...; lcm(a, b) = p**m ... where m = max(d, e)
assert e <= m
d = 0 if m == e else m
```

Для маленьких чисел, можно находить простые множители перебором всех делителей:

```py
def a(b, lcm):
    """Find *a* given *lcm(a, b)* and *b*."""
    a = 1
    p = 2  # prime factor
    while p * p <= b:
        # find multiplicity of p in b
        e = 0  # b = p**e * ...
        while b % p == 0:  # found prime factor
            e += 1  # increase multiplicity
            b //= p
            assert lcm % p == 0
            lcm //= p

        # find multiplicity of p in lcm
        # lcm = p**m * ...
        m = e
        while lcm % p == 0:  # d = max(d, e)
            m += 1  # increase multiplicity
            lcm //= p

        # a = p**d * ...
        if m > e:  # max(d, e) > e
            a *= p**m  # d == m
        else:  # d = 0
            assert m == e
        p += 1
    assert lcm % b == 0  # last prime factor or 1
    if lcm % b**2 != 0:  # e = max(d, e)
        lcm //= b
    return a * lcm
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def a(b, lcm):
    """Find *a* given *lcm(a, b)* and *b*."""
    a = 1
    p = 2  # prime factor
    while p * p <= b:
        # find multiplicity of p in b
        e = 0  # b = p**e * ...
        while b % p == 0:  # found prime factor
            e += 1  # increase multiplicity
            b //= p
            assert lcm % p == 0
            lcm //= p

        # find multiplicity of p in lcm
        # lcm = p**m * ...
        m = e
        while lcm % p == 0:  # d = max(d, e)
            m += 1  # increase multiplicity
            lcm //= p

        # a = p**d * ...
        if m > e:  # max(d, e) > e
            a *= p**m  # d == m
        else:  # d = 0
            assert m == e
        p += 1
    assert lcm % b == 0  # last prime factor or 1
    if lcm % b**2 != 0:  # e = max(d, e)
        lcm //= b
    return a * lcm
    
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
    
def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)
    
from browser import document
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    b = int(document["b"].value)
    lcm_ = int(document["lcm"].value)
    a_ = a(b, lcm_)
    assert lcm_ == lcm(a_, b)
    print(f"a={a_}, b={b}, lcm={lcm(a_,b)}")
on_click('dummy on start')    
</script><label for="b">b:&nbsp;</label><input id="b" value="16"> <label for="lcm">lcm:&nbsp;</label><input id="lcm" value="80"> <button id="mybutton">Найти a</button></body>
```

Примеры использования:

```py
>>> a(b=28, lcm=84)
3
>>> a(b=21, lcm=84)
4
>>> lcm(a(b=3, lcm=84), 3)
84
>>> a(b=2, lcm=4)
4
>>> a(b=4, lcm=4)
1
>>> a(b=20, lcm=80)
16
>>> a(b=16, lcm=80)
5
>>> a(b=1, lcm=lcm(2, 1))
2
>>> a(b=2, lcm=lcm(2, 1))
1
>>> lcm(a(b=2, lcm=lcm(2, 1)), 2)
2
```

где `lcm(a, b)`:

```py
from math import gcd

def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение без явной факторизации. Сложность не больше чем число простых делителей числа (а в среднем значительно быстрее).

Пусть у нас есть равенство `НОК = а*b/НОД(a,b)` Или `НОК/а = b/НОД(a,b)`. Нам нужно минимизировать b. Левая часть дана по условию. Понятно что минимум будет, при минимуме НОД. Пусть он равен 1. Тогда `b1 = НОК/а`. Любое b будет делиться на `b1` (думаю очевидно) и может быть записано как `b1 * c1`. Дальше. c1 будет делиться на НОД(a,b1). Продолжать итерационно пока не остановится процесс.

Код короче чем объяснение =)

```
long calc(long nok, long first){
    if (nok % first != 0)
        return -1; //wrong input
    long res = nok/first;
    long g = 1;
    long tmp;
    while ( (tmp = gcd(first, res)) != g){
        g = tmp;
        res = nok/first * g;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Запускаемый пример с тестированием https://ideone.com/HdBNgj